# weird glm::mat2x4 assignment behaviour

Tags: c++, glm-math

I am trying to load freetype chars, stuff them into a texture as subimages and then render them instanced.
While most of it seems to work, right now I have a problem with storing the texture coordinates into a glm::mat2x4 matrix.

As can be seen below each character has a struct with information I right now deem necessary, including a matrix called face, which should store the texture coordinates.

But when it comes to assigning the coordinates, after leaving the loop in which it takes place, suddenly all the values go crazy, without any (wanted/ intended) operation taking place from my side.

After creating the texture atlas with freetype and putting all my structs into the map, I assign the width and height of my texture `aw` & `ah` to a storage class called c_atlas.

I calculate the texture coordinates in the loop shown below, make the glm::mat2x4 a 0.0f matrix and then stuff them into it. Couting them into the console gives the values I want.
After leaving the for loop I start another one, browsing over the matrix and cout them into the console, which gives me more or less random values in the range of e^-23 to e^32.

All of this happens in `namespace foo` and is called in a constructor of a class in the same namespace (sth. like this:)

```
foo::class::constructor()
{
  call_function();
}
int main()
{
  foo::class c;
  c.call_function();
}
```

I crafted a minimum working example, but unfortunatly I am not able to replicate the error.

So I have the following loop running (a part of `call_function()`:

```
namespace foo
{
  namespace alphabet
  {
    const char path_arial[] = "res/font/consola.ttf";
    class character
    {
    public:
      glm::vec2 advance;
      glm::vec2 bearing;
      glm::vec2 size;
      glm::vec2 offset;
      glm::mat2x4 face;
    };
    std::map<char, character> char_map;
    FT_Library m_ftlib;
    FT_Face m_ftface;

    GLuint m_VBO, m_VAO;
  }
  c_atlas ascii;
}
void foo::call_function()
{
  //creating all the charactur structs with freetype and store them in the char_map

  std::ofstream f("atlas_data.csv", std::ios::openmode::_S_app);
  f << "letter;topleft.x;topleft.y;topright.x;topright.y;bottomright.x;bottomright.y;bottomleft.x;bottomleft.y" << std::endl;
  for(auto c : alphabet::char_map)
  {
    std::cout << "b4: " << c.second.offset.x;
    c.second.offset /= glm::vec2(aw,ah);
    std::cout << "\nafter: " << c.second.offset.x << std::endl;
    glm::vec2 ts = c.second.size/glm::vec2(aw,ah);
    //couts the right values

    uint16_t n = 0;
    c.second.face = glm::mat2x4(0.0f);
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << c.first << " at init:\n";
      std::cout << c.second.face[0][i] << "\n";
      std::cout << c.second.face[1][i] << std::endl;
    }
    //couts the right values

    c.second.face[0][n++] = c.second.offset.x;
    c.second.face[0][n++] = c.second.offset.y;
    c.second.face[0][n++] = c.second.offset.x+ts.x;
    c.second.face[0][n++] = c.second.offset.y;
    n = 0;
    c.second.face[1][n++]= c.second.offset.x+ts.x;
    c.second.face[1][n++] = c.second.offset.y+ts.y;
    c.second.face[1][n++] = c.second.offset.x;
    c.second.face[1][n++]= c.second.offset.y+ts.y;
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << c.first << " assigned:\n";
      std::cout << c.second.face[0][i] << "\n";
      std::cout << c.second.face[1][i] << std::endl;
    }
    //still couts the right values

    f  << (char)c.first << ";" << c.second.face[0].x << ";" << c.second.face[0].y << ";" << c.second.face[0].z << ";" << c.second.face[0].w << ";" << c.second.face[1].x << ";" << c.second.face[1].y << ";" << c.second.face[1].z << ";" << c.second.face[1].w << std::endl;
    //the file also have the right values
  }
  f.close();

  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
  //yet here all the values totally off track, i.e. e^32 or e^-23 (while they should all be between 0.01f - 1.0f)
  for(auto i : alphabet::char_map)
  {
    std::cout << "\ntopleft:\n";
    std::cout << "X: " << i.second.face[0].x << " | " << "Y: " << i.second.face[0].x;
    std::cout << "\ntopright:\n";
    std::cout << "X: " << i.second.face[0].z << " | " << "Y: " << i.second.face[0].w;
    std::cout << "\nbotleft:\n";
    std::cout << "X: " << i.second.face[1].x << " | " << "Y: " << i.second.face[1].x;
    std::cout << "\nbotright:\n";
    std::cout << "X: " << i.second.face[1].z << " | " << "Y: " << i.second.face[1].w;
  }
}
```

my mwe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include <map>

struct bin
{
  glm::mat2x4 mat;
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    std::map<char, bin> bucket;
    uint16_t r = 0;
    for(uint16_t n = 0; n < 7; ++n)
    {
      glm::vec4 v = glm::vec4(0.12128f, 0.12412f, 0.15532f, 0.23453f);
      bin b;
      r = 0;
      b.mat[0][r++] = v.x;
      b.mat[0][r++] = v.y;
      b.mat[0][r++] = v.z;
      b.mat[0][r++] = v.w;
      r = 0;
      b.mat[1][r++] = v.x;
      b.mat[1][r++] = v.y;
      b.mat[1][r++] = v.z;
      b.mat[1][r++] = v.w;
      bucket[n] = b;
    }

    for(auto it : bucket)
    {
      r = 0;
      std::cout << "0:\t" << it.second.mat[0][0] << "\t" << it.second.mat[0][1] << "\t" << it.second.mat[0][2] << "\t" << it.second.mat[0][3] << "\n";
      r = 0;
      std::cout << "1:\t" << it.second.mat[1][0] << "\t" << it.second.mat[1][1] << "\t" << it.second.mat[1][2] << "\t" << it.second.mat[1][3] << std::endl;

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Right now I am totally lost, especially as my mwe works fine. 
I am clueless what goes wrong after leaving the for-loop, so thanks for any thought on that!

Indeed, I could just rewrite that section and hope it would work - as my mwe does. But I would like to find out/ get help on finding out what exactly happens between the "assign" for loop and the "retrieve" for loop. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear. Is `char_map` a global variable? Is it used in multiple files? If so, have you properly defined it with `extern`?

Comment: 'char_map' is part of the alphabet namespace, only used in the cpp where the above code is in. alphabet is a namespace within the namespace foo. I edited the code to make it more clear, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work for me now:

Appartenly assigning the values this way:

```
for(auto c : alphabet::char_map)
{
  c.second.face[0][n++] = c.second.offset.x;
  //and so on
}
```

Did not work properly (for whatever reason..)
Changing this into a `for(uint16_t i = 32; i < 128; ++i)` worked for me. Also it was just the assigning loop, the `auto`-iterating ofer the map elsewhere works just fine.